# Why do we need the type of i31 in WasmGC proposal?

Tags: webassembly

Why do we need the type of i31 in the WasmGC proposal? The difference between it and primitive scalar is only the tagging bit, is that right? Also, I saw from the spec that an i31 is not actually allocated in the store, so why is it regarded as a heap type? Since AFAIK, GC only cares about the object data in the heap.

Spec: https://webassembly.github.io/gc/core/syntax/types.html#syntax-heaptype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An i31 is compatible with other references. That means it can be used as part of a union with other reference types, unlike ordinary numeric types, which have an incompatible representation.

This reflects a common implementation technique in managed language runtimes, where tagging bits distinguish pointers from unboxed integers. This is used internally e.g. in JavaScript engines and many other dynamic and functional languages. Wasm, as a low-level VM, needs to make it available to runtimes implemented on top of its GC mechanism.

It is a heap type in so far that it lives in the same space as other heap types, and a GC must be able to dynamically distinguish i31s from genuine pointers when it traverses the heap.

Comment: If so, does it mean we cannot use integers produced for example by i32.const for heap types? .e.g *(struct (field (i32)))* Since the engine needs to be able to distinguish integer from pointer to object when scanning the heap.

Comment: Oh, seems this won't incur any performance penalty since the GC could rely on the type information from Wasm to determine which field to scan, right? The field marked as i32 or i31 will be skipped.

Comment: You can use i32 in structs, but a struct always requires an allocation. You want to use i31 to avoid allocation where possible, but still be compatible with references. For example, a function that takes an anyref can be passed an i31ref. (And for a struct field of type anyref, the GC will need to look at the tag bit to decide whether to traverse it as a pointer, the static type doesn't say.)

Comment: “And for a struct field of type anyref, the GC will need to look at the tag bit to decide whether to traverse it as a pointer, the static type doesn't say”, how does the GC know which detailed type of object the anyref refers to when traversing it as a pointer?

Comment: Oh, I think the header of the boxed value would maintain the type information at runtime, right?

Comment: Right, heap-allocated objects carry a descriptor at runtime.